# Uploading local files with browserstack using Protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor, browserstack

I have a simple script which is trying to upload a file directly to my application. This test works fine on my local setup (win10 + chrome 73) however when running through browserstack-local (which as I understand sets up a secure connection to my local machine) I am receiving the following error.

```
Failed: invalid argument: File not found : C:\correctPath/correctFileName.zip
[Chrome #01]         (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
[Chrome #01]         (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

I am printing out the following confirmations so I know that the paths are correct.

[image: Code]

Which produces

```
[Chrome #01] File Path: C:\correctPath/correctFileName.zip
[Chrome #01] File exists: true
```

These are printed before the failure occurs.

**Note:** I can run tests which do not require uploading files fine.

I am brand new to browserstack so there may be something simple I am missing. Any help or advise would be appreicated.

---

### Answer:

Corey pointed me in the right direction with his answer. I needed to add the following two lines to my onPrepare in my config file and I can upload fine now.

```
const remote = require('selenium-webdriver/remote');
await browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());
```

Comment: please don't post screenshots of code

Comment: @Corey I didn't realize they rendered so small after I posted them. I have replaced them with extracts. The middle code snippet I am leaving as it is just for informational purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see "Local file detector" section at: https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/remote.html

> Local file detector
>
> The Local File Detector allows the transfer of files from the client
>   machine to the remote server. For example, if a test needs to upload a
>   file to a web application, a remote WebDriver can automatically
>   transfer the file from the local machine to the remote web server
>   during runtime. This allows the file to be uploaded from the remote
>   machine running the test.